# need to wait answer from retrofit request in MainActivity

Tags: java, android, retrofit

i have request in retrofit where return List which assign for my dataSet field. i did it in onResponse method. But initializing of recycle view in MainActivity is faster than request and view is showing nothing. What i can to do for waiting onResponse method.

I have this two methods in class NewsRepository.java

```
 private void setNews(){
    GetDataService service = RetrofitClientInstance.getRetrofitInstance().create(GetDataService.class);
    Call<ItemsAPI> call = service.getAllItems();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ItemsAPI>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ItemsAPI> call, Response<ItemsAPI> response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onResponse");
            items = response.body();
            dataSet = items.getItems();
            Log.d(TAG, dataSet.get(0).getTitle());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ItemsAPI> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onFailure "+ t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
public MutableLiveData<List<News>> getNews(){
    setNews();
    MutableLiveData<List<News>> data = new MutableLiveData<>();
    data.setValue(dataSet);
    return data;
}
```

And have this in MainActivityModelView.java

```
  public void init(){
    if(mNews != null){
        return;
    }
    mRepo = NewsRepository.getInstance();
    mNews = mRepo.getNews();
}
```

And this is MyActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

private RecyclerView mRecycleView;
private RecycleViewAdapter mAdapter;
private MainActivityViewModel mMainActivityViewModel;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mRecycleView = findViewById(R.id.recyclev_view);

    mMainActivityViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainActivityViewModel.class);

    mMainActivityViewModel.init();

    mMainActivityViewModel.getNews().observe((LifecycleOwner) this, new Observer<List<News>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable List<News> news) {
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    mMainActivityViewModel.getIsUpdating().observe((LifecycleOwner) this, new Observer<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable Boolean aBoolean) {
            if(aBoolean){
            }
            else{
                mRecycleView.smoothScrollToPosition(mMainActivityViewModel.getNews().getValue().size()-1);
            }
        }
    });

    initRecyclerView();
    Log.d(TAG, "RecycleView is inited");
}

private void initRecyclerView(){
    mAdapter = new RecycleViewAdapter(this, mMainActivityViewModel.getNews().getValue());
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecycleView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    mRecycleView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

}

The Activity is init is faster then my request.

```
2019-05-18 09:32:12.299 13859-13859/com.krasnov.rxjavalearning D/MainActivity: RecycleView is inited
2019-05-18 09:32:13.098 13859-13859/com.krasnov.rxjavalearning D/NewsRepository: onResponse
```

Comment: i have separeted logic and have different classes: Repository - for request and MainActivity - use adapter

Comment: show progress bar untill your request completed and on getting response hide progress bar

Comment: i have separeted logic, i can't  just use progress bar in repository class, where i get data from api

Comment: tell me exactly what you want

Comment: Please share your code at first!

Comment: update the question!

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better to move this code above othre code below findViewById

```
initRecyclerView();
Log.d(TAG, "RecycleView is inited");
```

In this function its better to not use this constractor

```
mAdapter = new RecycleViewAdapter(this, mMainActivityViewModel.getNews().getValue());
```

Use this instead (create this constractor)

```
 mAdapter = new RecycleViewAdapter(this);
```

And when your data arrive fire this function in adapter

```
 public void setData( List<News> list) {
    this.list= list
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

So your code is like

```
mMainActivityViewModel.getNews().observe((LifecycleOwner) this, new Observer<List<News>>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(@Nullable List<News> news) {
        mAdapter.setData(news)
    }
});
```

Comment: @flex_grigorowicz ok what happens?

Comment: @flex_grigorowicz hello?

Answer (score 0):

in your onResponse  you should notify adapter add this:

```
        yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: logic with adapter is located in another class.

Answer (score 0):

> On resume call the retrofit service, 
>   after response create a callback
>   method in ViewModel to notify in Activty class, after notified then 
>   initialise recyclerview.

.